# Google Maps Android API v2 Route Overlay

Tags: android, overlay, routes, google-maps-android-api-2

Playing around with the new API today to see if I can port my current app to it, I see that there is no `MapView.getOverlays().add(...);`
Conceptually, it seems hard to imagine how an overlay which was previously 2D, would be rearranged when the map is tilted.

I see that there is functionality for something called `GroundOverlay` but this does not look applicable to my case. I also see `Polyline` and this looks better suited to my purpose.

Does anyone have any idea on how, or if one will be able to add a route overlay (I'm using the Directions API) using the mapping API v2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's done with `Polyline`. From the example on the Google Developers page - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline

```
GoogleMap map;
   // ... get a map.
   // Add a thin red line from London to New York.
   Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
       .add(new LatLng(51.5, -0.1), new LatLng(40.7, -74.0))
       .width(5)
       .color(Color.RED));
```

Comment: Hi @qubz, is there a way to draw not a straight line between the two points but rather drawing the path between them?

Comment: If by path you mean route, you can use Googles Directions API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/ with Polylines to do this.

Comment: Thank you @qubz do you have any example of this using API v2? I can't find unfortunately.